# Progressbar with two colours

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I have an application with questions and want to show a progress bar to show how many questions that are left/answered. 
I would like to have the colour of the progress bar green if the question was correct answered and red if the answer was wrong.

Let say there are 5 questions. After e.g. 3 questions, the progress bar should be

```
green|red|red|grey|grey
```

if question 1 was correct and 2 and 3 were wrong...

Comment: a progressbar doesn't seem the best match for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a working solution.. Probably not the best, so comments are appriciated!

in my **xml-file**

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/info"
      />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/take_test_progress_bar_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/info"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/take_test_progress_bar_linear_layout"
        android:text="@string/stt1"
        />
```

And in my **activity**:

```
oncreate(){
....

LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
for(int k=0; k<mTotalQuestionNum; k++)
{
    View v = new View(this);
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

    params.weight = (float)1.0/( (float) mTotalQuestionNum);
    v.setLayoutParams(params);
    mProgressLayout.addView(v,k);

}
...
}
```

Then, when handling answers...

```
if(correct)
    mProgressLayout.getChildAt(mQuestionNum-1).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
else
    mProgressLayout.getChildAt(mQuestionNum-1).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't at the computer all weekend - glad you've solved your problem. My only note would be that your `weight` calculation is unnecessary, just set the `weight` of them all to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

As njzk2 said in the comments, a `ProgressBar` isn't the right component for the job.

I'd suggest using a `LinearLayout`.

You can programatically add as many `Views` inside it as you need, using weights for equal horizontal distribution, and you can change the background colour of these `Views` as the user progresses through your questions.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try... My tags were maybe a bit confusing, since it still will be a progress bar, but not an Android `progressbar`...

Comment: If you have problems implementing it, I'll throw together some sample code for you. Best of luck

Comment: Some help would be appreciated, @Rawkode! :)